# Protecting 6502 decimal mode code from interrupts

Tags: assembly, 6502, binary-coded-decimal

A common idiom in 6502 assembly code is to protect sequences of code that rely on decimal mode from being interrupted. This because an interrupt handler typically clears decimal mode (`cld`), and thus the protected routine needs this. It looks like this:

```
sei
sed
...
some decimal mode math ops
...
cld
cli
```

A possible downside here is that maybe this code is called from within an interrupt handler and re-enables interrupts when they should still be inhibited (so as to not overlap). So I see the following approach as both equivalent and "better", since it accounts for that case:

```
php
sei
sed
...
plp
```

Is this correct and should this be the "preferred" way to protect decimal code from interrupts? Any downsides?

Comment: Far as I remember decimal mode is restored if it was active by the `RTI` at the end of the interrupt handling code. The bug is decimal mode isn't cleared when entering an interrupt on NMOS processors (it was fixed on CMOS versions).

Comment: @Brian Are you saying the `sei` instruction (and the paired `cli`) is unnecessary to begin with?

Comment: In your use case yes. Disabling interrupts around decimal mode code would only be necessary to protect against execution of interrupt handling code that doesn't clear decimal mode and then misbehaves when it is set. Again only on a NMOS 6502.

Comment: @Brian Makes sense. So this is better described as a precaution against "buggy" interrupt handlers (which might be outside your own code; part of an "OS"), right?

Comment: @BrianH You can't protect against buggy interrupt handlers... in this case, you'd be protecting against an interrupt handler that deliberately altered the saved status registers on the stack, which means any status flag could potentially be different right before its value is tested, so no code is safe. Wrapping decimal-mode code that is otherwise free of race conditions doesn't make sense. Do you have an example of well-known code that does this?

Comment: Having code which disables interrupts saving the interrupt-enable status beforehand and restore it afterward is good policy except in cases where stack space is extremely limited; it's an issue which is often relevant in modern microcontroller libraries as well (and one which all too many vendors botch).

Comment: @fadden: When an interrupt handler returns, the decimal mode flag will be the same as it was when the interrupt was invoked, even if the interrupt itself changes it.  On the other hand, it's was hardly uncommon for interrupt handlers to use ADC and SBC without first ensuring the decimal flag was clear.

Comment: @supercat I see... protecting buggy handlers, not protecting *against* buggy handlers (per se).

Comment: @supercat Stack space is *always limited* on a 6502.

Comment: @tofro: Relatively few 6502 applications are within a byte, or even 16 bytes, of maxing out the stack, though I've written some games that were always within four bytes of maxing out the stack (since the stack only *was* four bytes!).

Comment: Why would you need to do decimal arithmetic in an interrupt handler?!

Comment: Stack space is always 256 bytes unless you are using page 1 for something weird. I wrote games for the VIC-20 in assembly, and I never had occasion to do *that*.

Comment: So like, shouldn't code written to run on an NMOS 6502 ensure that its interrupt handlers clear the decimal flag themselves before doing anything else?

Comment: @Kaz Well they *should be aware they can't assume a specific default state of this flag*. An ISR in a BCD pocket calculator probably wants to have the decimal flag set, an ISR in a Commodore C64 probably doesn't. It all depends. That's why it is very understandable the designers didn't assume a *default state* - And I'm not willing to call this "a bug". That is a common problem with global flags, the 8086's *direction flag* for string operations has the same. And nobody calls it "a bug" there.

Comment: @tofro Right? I mean all sorts of machine state is typically unknown in an ISR. Processors do not clear every register after saving it. Almost nothing can typically be relied upon. More advanced processors arrange for a separate stack for ISRs  because you can't trust the stack pointer.   I think the real bug was ISRs not clearing the flag, and so the CMOS version of the 6502 was compensating for buggy ISR code, rather than fixing a 6502 bug.

Comment: @Kaz: If a system doesn't use decimal mode, starting the ISR with 
a CLD instruction would add two cycles to the time required to process every interrupt.  Depending upon what a program is doing, guarding code that uses decimal mode may be better than including a CLD within every interrupt, especially if e.g. one is using raster interrupts many times per frame, but only performs decimal math during vblank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prohibiting interrupts around a decimal mode operation is a pattern to protect the interrupt service routine, not the decimal code sequences.

As was already emphasized by others, an interrupt automatically pushes the status register upon the stack. This includes the decimal bit. When the interrupt routine finishes, the RTI instruction pulls back that value and restores the original state of the decimal flag.

So your code example makes sense, but for protecting the interrupt handler code, not vice versa.

Your second code example addresses the case of calls from an interrupt handler properly, because the php / plp preserves the original state of the interrupt flag.

Another way to avoid problems would be to clear the decimal mode at the beginning of the interrupt handler (or having a handler that avoids instructions being affected by the decimal mode). It would add just a CLD to the beginning of the handler (because the original state is restored by RTI at the end) which has less effect on the timing than the possible jitter created with an SEI ... CLI block.

Comment: I'm not sure what "protecting the interrupt handler" is supposed to mean. Protect from what?. You can only protect it from it's own non-optimal programming. As you rightly say, an ISR that needs to have the decimal flag set to a specific state should just set it to that state. If it doesn't do that, it's just wrong.

Comment: @tofro This may be referring to the bug on the NMOS versions of the 6502. (See comments under question.) The bug is that the processor failsto clear the decimal flag when dispatching the ISR.  In that case, disabling interrupts around code which sets the decimal flag protects interrupts from this bug. Still it seems like a minor thing? Any interrupt code whose instructions are influenced by this flag should just clear it itself.

Comment: @Kaz I think its questionable whether this can be called *a bug* - The manuals very clearly say "Make a convention for the "standard setting" of the decimal flag and make sure if you set it otherwise, you re-set it back to the standard. They also make no promise whatsoever that the decimal flag would have a certain state in an ISR, rather the opposite: "Set it if you need it"

Comment: The 8086 has a very similar problem with the direction flag - but nobody seems to call it *a bug* that it doesn't have a default state in an ISR.

Comment: @tofro sometimes you are not in charge of the ISR code. For example, the Commodore 64 Kernal ISR does not clear the decimal flag and is using commands affected by it. Thus, if you want to write a piece of code without changing the existing ISR, the approach presented by Brian makes sense.

Comment: You only need to clear decimal flag in your interrupt routine if you use adc/sbc in there.

Answer (score 22):

### TL;DR:

> Protecting 6502 decimal mode code from interrupts

Decimal mode does not need to be protected from interrupts.

Decimal mode is not cancelled/changed by interrupt routines(*1).

1. Decimal mode is recorded in a status register flag (SED/CLD)
2. When entering an interrupt, the status register is pushed on the stack
3. When leaving an interrupt it is pulled back

See also the [Interrupts and Decimal Mode remarks](http://6502.org/tutorials/decimal_mode.html#5) of the [6502 Decimal Mode Tutorial](http://6502.org/tutorials/decimal_mode.html)

If at all, then buggy interrupt routines may need to be protected from decimal mode :))

---

### In Detail

> A common idiom in 6502 assembly code is to protect sequences of code that rely on decimal mode from being interrupted.

Serious? I have never seen that sequence in 40 years of 6502 programming - at least not for the purpose mentioned. It does not make much sense - except, see below.

Also, disabling interrupts does not disable NMI (or RESET), so even with that 'protection' an NMI may come along.

> This because an interrupt handler typically clears decimal mode

Well, yes, interrupt code using ADC/SBC needs to set the mode it expects - usually binary. After all, an interrupt can happen any time, with decimal set or cleared, so the called interrupt routine has to set it the way needed. It does not have to set it back, as that's inherently done by RTI.

---

### Fringe cases where it may make sense

- One very, very rare case where it would make sense, is if an (expected) interrupt routine has no room for the two clock cycles needed to clear the decimal flag (CLD).

  Except, such a routine would usually as well be delicate to delayed interrupt activation - which is what that code does.
- The other, maybe a bit more common one, is to accommodate interrupt routines that do not clear the decimal flag, but do assume it to be cleared **and** which can not be changed or enhanced to handle the decimal flag.

  This is usually the case when a program has been added to an environment were such a routine is already existing, stored in ROM with the interrupt pointer as well in ROM and pointing direct to this routine, with no way to hook.

  In all other cases, it should be possible to hook the interrupt, clear decimal and continue with the existing routine.

  Well, or changing the CPU to a 65C02, which does clear the decimal flag after saving the flag register, but before entering the interrupt code.

---

### The 'Better' Approach

Well, saving the interrupt enable flag, before disabling is for sure not a bad idea, but it's slow and only to be taken if one has absolute no idea about the environment the routine is used in. Otherwise it is, like disabling interrupts when doing decimal, a great waste of time and resources.

### It's the Environment, Stupid.

Saving the decimal state and even more so disabling interrupts should be avoided and never become the default case.

Using/setting decimal should be, like any other state and data changing behaviour, be part of a routines description, enabling users of such routines to work accordingly - like simply (re-)setting the wanted state after a subroutine again.

Disabling interrupts is even worse, as it changes the response to interrupts in a rather random manner, creating the worst kind of bugs to be searched. Just imagine some machine using raster interrupts to manage screen output. If some foreground program disables interrupts not synchronized with screen timing, some of the raster interrupts may sometimes fall a bit late, creating ugly glitches. Good luck in finding why and which routine and when does create one.

It's almost universally better to make sure the interrupts are compatible with either setting of the decimal flag.

---

*1 - Except for processing time taken and unless the interrupt code does willingly manipulate the saved flag register or returns without using an RTI.

Comment: The code `php/sei/sed ... plp` is the same size as `sei/sed / cld/cli` and only three cycles longer (11 cycles versus 8).  Whether or not it should be considered preferable to the latter form, I wouldn't classify it as a "great" waste of time and resources.

Comment: @supercat Any code that is not needed to solve an existing issue is waste of space and time. Keep in mind, the question is about a preferred way, not for circumvention of some very specific situation. So both code fragments are not to be used by default.

Comment: _"saving the interrupt enable flag, before disabling is for sure **not** a bad idea.  It's slow and..."_ - what are you trying to say here?

Comment: @BruceAbbott well, I guess I could add a _'But...'_ :)

Answer (score 4):

There's absolutely no reason for an interrupt service routine to save and restore the decimal flag - On interrupt, the flag is being saved to the stack automatically, and restored on RTI, so any "normal" code is seeing no change whatsoever, regardless of what the ISR does (except if it would manipulate the value on the stack, which is probably a bad idea anyways).

That also means that ISRs shouldn't assume a specific value of the decimal flag - if they need it set or re-set, they should set it so, but there's no need for a restore.

For the same reason, there's absolutely no need to disable interrupts in code that is working in decimal mode.

Comment: One more, there is no need to clear decimal bit in interrupts if you do not use adc/sbc in your interrupt routine.